# Adobe Illustrator - Pen tool problem (isometric design)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, isometric

I am following a tutorial for isometric design. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFHxknDs4Mk&t=208s)

My problem is when I finished the first path as in the tutorial I can not start a new one which continues the old one.

It shows me "delete anchor point" even I set normal pen tool. And when I set the "add anchor point tool" it shows me "Please use the add anchor point tool on segment of a path".

I will post here the screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Deselect (Ctrl+Shift+A) your previous path if you are going to draw a new starting from a point where already exists a node of the previous path. Otherwise you kill the existing node.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Didn't view the video)</sub>

I'm **guessing** here.....

You can use the **Pen Tool** to click the end anchor on a path and then continue that path. You don't need the Minus Anchor or Add Anchor tools. The regular Pen Tool does this.

Where you *might* be having the problem *could* be due to **object stacking**.

If the end anchor you want to click is *below* another path, then the pen tool will *always* see the top object and *never* the anchor below it.

The solution it to change the *stacking order* of the objects so that the **open path** you want to continue is *on top* of other objects. Using the **Selection Tool** (black arrow), click the open path and choose `Object > Bring to Front`. Then go back to the Pen Tool and try continuing the path.